# Build fails in xcode

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

[image: xcode error]

xcode version - 12.4
react-native verson - 0.64

Suddenly build started to fail. Did not add any new library.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by deleteing node modules and installing it again